# CSS Width - Nexus 4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, width

I've been trying to set the width of my body to equal the width of my Nexus 4 screen which I heard was 768px. However, I find that when the phone is in the upright position I can scroll to the right a fair amount... If I halve the width to 384px, I can still scroll to the right slightly...

I am using Bootstrap.

HTML:

```
<body>

<div class="container">         
    <h1>Heading</h1>
</div>

<div class="container"> 
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Settings</button>   
</div>

<div class="container"> 
    <button class="btn-primary">Received Messages</button>  
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
background-image: url("wooden-floor.jpg");
width:384px;    
text-align: center;
}

button {
margin-top:25px;    
}

.container {
width:384px;
}
```

Would anyone know what I should do to correct this?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you using the viewport meta tag?

Comment: @Leeish are you referring to this ` <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`? If so, yes I am.

Comment: Yes I was. Is there any padding/margin on the body or anything in the body? I know it's not listed, but just asking. The reason sometimes pixels counts mean shit is because of the screen density issue. Ex. iPhone retina has more pixels than you actually put in your css. Without seeing all your css it's hard to say. Start removing stuff until it works. Like just do a body tag with a color BG and go from there.

Comment: @codehorse Thanks for that. But out of curiosity, why is the pixel method not working?

Answer (score 0):

Try using media queries in your css and see the results.see below:

click to see help

http://cssmediaqueries.com/what-are-css-media-queries.html

Also in html

```
<meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0' name='viewport'>
```

what about viewport?

Comment: Hi Suku, actually I was using the following already in my HTML `<link href="css/index.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-device-width: 768px)"> `.

Comment: @Era Yes, I am using that.